# File gets locked if users open document from SPO library mapped as a network drive

Tags: error, excel, spo, network-drive

From our SPO tenant, i added couple of document libraries as network drive.

First time when I open the document, it opens fine and I'm able to make changes and save it successfully.

Next time, when i try to open(after few minutes), the document is not opening and displays the error "Sorry couldn't open the file Z:\folder\document.xlsx

When i try to edit the same document in browser, i get an error saying that the file is locked/checked out by me for editing.

I cleared all the cache but still the issue persists.This is happening for all the documents and for all the users.

Kindly guide if there is any workaround to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, stop using network drives. Use the OneDrive sync client, instead or open directly from the web interface.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/cannot-release-lock-on-sharepoint-online-file/m-p/216475#M19782